# Array of pointers returned my Malloc/Calloc in Objective-C

Tags: objective-c, arrays, pointers

Let's say I have the following:

```
MyClass *__strong*matches = (MyClass*__strong*)calloc([myArray count], sizeof([MyClass class]));
```

If I would like to refer to the second pointer in `matches`, would I write `matches[1]` or would I write `matches[4]`? I am confused because I know that pointers take up 4 bytes, but my program crashes due to a memory error if I follow the logic of `matches[4]` and my program works perfectly when filling `matches` if I follow the logic of `matches[1]`.

Furthermore, which would apply if I used `malloc` instead of `calloc`?

Comment: 2nd pointer is matches[1]. and calloc is correct, it just initializes all memory locations to 0.

Comment: Thanks @OmidCompSCI! And do you mind explaining internally how that works? Like why that is true? I'm just trying to fully wrap my head around it.

Comment: Nothing with pointers taking up 4 bytes, pointers POINT to a memory location, they do not take up actual memory you shouldn't at least think of them doing so, rather something else has taken up the memory, but pointers just "stand on top"/point to that thing taken up the memory already. And matches[4], probably doesn't work because your not allocating that much space, I don't know how many places you are allocating, that is up to what [myArray count] is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is `matches[1]` because the compiler knows from the type (`MyClass * __strong *matches`) the size of the items (pointers in your case) that the pointer is pointing at and uses that to determine how to compile the index operation.

For comparison consider `int x[4]` vs. `char y[4]`, indexing does not mean "byte offset 4" from the start of the array but "*item* 4" where *item* in this case is an `int` (probably 4 or 8 bytes) or `char` (1 byte). You have pointers (probably 4 or 8 bytes) in your "array" and the compiler knows that from the type.

HTH